# Function of "the most recent" in a sentence

Tags: superlatives

> “Depending on the type of dance (round dance “for nearby and tail-wagging dance, with variable tempo, for further away and how far), the other bees can work out where this newly discovered feast can be found. Doesn't this ability of the bee to indicate a location some distance away mean that bee communication has at least some degree of displacement as a feature? Yes, but it is displacement of a very limited type. It just doesn't have the range of possibilities found in human language. Certainly, the bee can direct other bees to a food source. However, ***it must be the most recent food source. ”***

I am wondering what the bold sentence could mean?
 What is more, could you please take an example like the very function of using ***the most*** above?

Extracted  From: George Yule. “The Study Of Language.” iBooks.

Any comment would be appreciated

Cheers,
 nima

Comment: The word, **recent**, in the sentence in question is used as an **adjective**. **The most recent** is its **superlative form**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Certainly, the bee can direct other bees to a food source. However, it must be **the most recent** food source.*

The last sentence there is modifying the one before it in a way that draws attention to the limitations of bee communication. A bee can direct other bees to *the most recent* food source the first bee found.